# How to use service override when service is declared in final class?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Overriding services a feature introduced in PrestaShop 1.7.3 (https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/concepts/services/#override-the-service)
However, how could one override a service that is declared with class final? For instance `CarrierForOrderChoiceProvider`?
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/develop/src/Adapter/Form/ChoiceProvider/CarrierForOrderChoiceProvider.php

Here is the real problem:
Not all orders come from PS frontoffice. Some of them come from other shopping carts like  Amazon for example, thus, these orders don't have their corresponding carts in PS database.

For the service `CarrierForOrderChoiceProvider`, it relies on the cart object to retrieve some data (id_address_delivery, id_customer..). For orders coming from Amazon, these data is empty since there is no cart object related to the order, which leads to empty carrier list.

A working solution is to replace:

```
 $cart = Cart::getCartByOrderId($options['order_id']);
 $groups = Customer::getGroupsStatic((int) $cart->id_customer);
 $address = new Address((int) $cart->id_address_delivery);
```

By:

```
$order = new Order((int)$options['order_id']);
$groups = Customer::getGroupsStatic((int) $order->id_customer);
$address = new Address((int) $order->id_address_delivery);
```

What is the best solution here?

1. create a PR that just removes the keyword `final` so that it is possible to use service override for this class and allow merchants create module for their specific shops?
2. create a PR that replace the code like above (rely on Order object and not Cart object).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried "Decorate service" ?

Comment: @MahdiShad, I got same suggestion by another guy and I am trying to make it work. I still get errors related to service arguments, but it seems the new service has replaced the old one for core functionnality. Thanks a lot